# Twitter API: What should I do next after completing apply for Twitter API and verifying email?

Tags: api, twitter

I'm planning to make a Twitter bot, and I've just completed apply for using Twitter API an hour ago and created API key at the Developer Portal page.
However, I don't know what is left for me to be enabled to use the API.

I guess my next task is just waiting for my apply is going to be passed for several days or weeks, but I've not received any email which tells me I have to wait for the screening being done. All I received
from Twitter so far is the email titled `Verify your Twitter Developer`, which I've verified.

Is it ok to just wait for the email from Twitter?

I'm sorry if my question is not really programming problem, but I can't find any answer for it.

The image below is the page I'm now in:
[image: page]

Addition:

I've already got `API key & secret (Consumer key)` and `Bearer token`, but not yet `Access token & secret`. Can I already use Twitter API or do I have to wait
for screening and get `Access token & secret` first?

The image below is the Keys and tokens page:
[image]

Comment: This page says you have access to the standard product track, so go into the Projects and Apps section and create a new project and app. You need the consumer key and secret from there.

Comment: Thank you. I've got  `API key & secret (Consumer key)` and `Bearer token` but not yet `Access token & secret`. Can I already use Twitter API or do I have to wait screening and get `Access token & secret` first?

Comment: You can generate an access token and secret right on that page. That will allow your bot to post as your own logged-in user. If you want to post from another account, you will need to read about 3-legged OAuth.